# Docker Compose - Remove dangling service

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

While getting to know docker and docker compose, I removed a volume that was still in use by docker compose.

Now, docker compose prints the following error message for everything I try to do (stop, start, ps, rm, ...):

> ERROR: Named volume "db_data:/var/lib/mysql:rw" is used in service "db" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.

Therefore, I am now unable to work with docker compose in any way. As I am out of ideas, I am reaching out for some support.

Comment: have you tried docker-compose up to restart all docker containers?

Comment: try to stop/rm (probably with some `--force` flag) this container using plain docker (docker-compose is just wrapper around docker)

Answer (score 0):

I usually have this bash script at hand:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Clean containters and images of docker.

#Stop containers
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)

#Remove docker containers:
docker rm $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -q)

# Remove docker images:
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

Example source: https://github.com/filfreire/scripts/blob/master/docker-clean-all